# Assign Variable to Case Statement In Stored Procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I am trying to assign a variable to a case statement in my stored procedure.

Here is my code :

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[myProcedure] 
(
    @StartDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @EndDate DATETIME = NULL,
)
AS
    DECLARE @Type varchar
    SET @Type = NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT DISTINCT 
       @Type = CASE 
                  WHEN myTable.myVariable = '1' 
                    THEN 'No' 
               END AS 'Test'
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.myDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
END
```

The error I am receiving is that `myTable.myVariable` multi-part identifier could not be bound.... I could be doing this completely wrong though... I am just trying to assign my case statement to the variable...

Comment: If am not wrong you cannot combine variable initialization with alias name to the source column. Try removing alias name `AS 'Test'`

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish - mostly because you're attempting to assign multiple rows from the results of your query to a scalar variable.  Also make sure to define the length of your varchar in `@type`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
DECLARE @I1 BIGINT
SET @I1 = (
SELECT  Top  1  CASE WHEN LIST_PRICE=75 THEN  [EAN]
      ELSE 0 END SPECIAL
  FROM dbo.x1)
  SELECT @I1
```